# pipe ffmpeg in Python

Tags: python, image, ffmpeg, rtsp

I have a working ffmpeg command which converts rtsp to image.

FFmpeg command here:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.200.230 -vf fps=fps=20/1 -vb 20M -qscale:v 2 img%d.jpg
```

I want to adapt the ffmpeg code into pipe code.

I tried to adapt it but It doesnt look right.

```
import subprocess
import numpy
import cv2


proc = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg',
    "-i", "rtsp://192.168.200.230/554",
    "-vf", "image2pipe",
    "fps", "20/1",                      
    "-qscale:v", "2",
    "-vb", "20M",
    "img%d.jpg"],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
)

while True:
    raw_image = proc.stdout.read(640 * 360 * 3)
    cv2.imshow('image', raw_image)
    cv2.waitKey()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    if not raw_image:
        break
    image =  numpy.fromstring(raw_image, dtype='uint8').reshape((640, 360, 3))
```

If u can also give me about placement hints ,It will be very usefull for me.I also want to call the image many times as value.And Im going to use it on vehicle detection.Gonna call it as a frame and doing processing.

This is the example of ffmpeg reading writing audio files in python.It can help you to guide.

http://zulko.github.io/blog/2013/10/04/read-and-write-audio-files-in-python-using-ffmpeg/

Comment: Which is the error you receive?

Comment: @lapinkoira nice question. I wrote the cv2.imshow...cv2.destroy part addionally without them i dont get any error. just ffmpeg screen comes disappear. It doesnt give any error. But When I add cv2. imshow waitkey lines It says                                                                                                                                               *File "C:\Users\Workingspace\Desktop\pipeeeeeworks.py", line 18, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('image', raw_image)
TypeError: mat is not a numpy array, neither a scalar*

Comment: That means raw_image is not an image, can you debug or print raw_image variable?

Comment: Do you have a rtsp point I can check? that's a private IP

Comment: @lapinkoira rtsp adress is working its just in local . My IP camera :).Print Command didnt change anything. I used cv2.imshow. It gave as u know. The problem is on ffmpeg converting code probably.I couldnt adapt it correctly